# Expo FileSystem.readAsStringAsync return wrong base64

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

I am trying to convert image into base64 but I didn't find any solution to resolve this issue. Actually, I got wrong base64 string could someone please help me how to convert image to base64

Thanks

```
      async fileToBase64(uri) {
    try {
      const content = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri);
    
     console.log('@@@ a',content)
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn('fileToBase64()', e.message);
      return '';
    }
  }
```

Comment: _How_ is it "wrong"? What is the actual value? What is the expected value? [Note the API: "..Default (encoding format) is FileSystem.EncodingType.UTF8.."](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemreadasstringasyncfileuri-options).

Comment: const file = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, {
                encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
            });

Comment: I am sending Base64

Comment: I don't have a solution handy for you, but I can attest to this not being the nonsensical question some may believe it to be at a glance. Can you include the inputs and outputs you're using?

Comment: It _is_ nonsensical (without additional information, as requested) because the OP does not supply the appropriate _context_ and _supporting information_ that is being seen: "I got wrong base64 string" - _were_, and what was it? "I am sending Base64" - no, that code is _not sending_ anything.